# Power BI Incremental Refresh with Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Has anyone successfully used the PBI incremental refresh with Snowflake as a data source?  A full refresh of my dataset (without incremental refresh) takes approximately 20 minutes, but with incremental refresh turned on, the data refresh times out because it takes longer than 120 minutes.  When looking at the query history in Snowflake, it looks like a 'SELECT *' query is being done again and again until it times out.

I've seen some posts that says 'query folding' is not supported by Snowflake while others say it's partially supported.

Any clarity would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We also had tried out multiple options to check if incremental refresh could be enabled for Snowflake Power BI combination.Two things we used to verify the details were

1. The query history from snowflake for the query which was sent from Power BI
2. Using diagnostics feature in power bi desktop which will show whether the source query was generated

Both of these indicated that query folding was not working and hence incremental refresh. Another option which we explored was if we can leverage Power BI Dataflows for incremental refresh. But this also was not supported directly.

We also are planning to try out one more "long cut" which might help us to implement incremental refresh:

1. Bring in an Azure ADLS gen2 storage between power bi and snowflake
2. We will need to bring in the data that needs to be incrementally loaded to ADLS
3. Power BI dataflows can be leveraged to do the incremental refresh for the Power BI Datasets from ADLS.

Not sure how much this will suit you. All the best

Thanks,
Prasanth

Comment: Thank you Prasanth, your response is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As on Aug 2020, Incremental refresh with Snowflake works in both Dataset and Data Flow. Verified with Query History in Snowflake.